# Unexpected token } in JSON at position 437

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I'm using Angular 5.0.0. And I want to connect `angular-bootstrap-md`. But when you start the application `ng s` an error occurs.

> error TS5014: Failed to parse file
>   'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/angular/tsconfig.json': Unexpected token } in
>   JSON at position 437.
>
> Error: error TS5014: Failed to parse file
>   'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/angular/tsconfig.json': Unexpected token } in
>   JSON at position 437.
>       at AngularCompilerPlugin._setupOptions (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:90:19)
>   at new AngularCompilerPlugin
>   (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\angular\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:43:14)
>   at _createAotPlugin
>   (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js:77:16)
>       at Object.getNonAotConfig (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js:100:19)
>   at NgCliWebpackConfig.buildConfig
>   (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-config.js:37:37)
>       at Class.run (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\tasks\serve.js:71:98)
>       at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\angular\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve.js:123:26)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

The first bracket stands out in red I can not understand why it seems all the brackets are closed

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": ["node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.ts"],
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
{
 "compileOnSave": false,
 "compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "declaration": false,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "target": "es5",
  "typeRoots": [
   "node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "lib": [
   "es2017",
   "dom"
  ]
 },
 "include": ["node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just remove the erroneous comma at the end in order to achieve a valid JSON file:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "es2017",
            "dom"
        ]
    },
    "include": ["node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

In case of doubt, you can check the validity using one of various tools, e.g. [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma at the end of this line:

```
"include": ["node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.ts"],
```