# Is there a simple straight forward "working" way to set up a node.js typescript project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, tsc

I'm unable to find standard instructions that help me set up a working `typescript` `node.js` project

I followed the popular tutorials like [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-a-node-project-with-typescript) & [Scotch](https://scotch.io/tutorials/setting-up-a-node-project-with-typescript) which are of no help!

1. Ran `npm run tsc -- --init` to generate a well-commented `tsconfig.json`.

> Initially `tsc --init` was not generating `tsconfig.json` but then I found that [adding `tsc` as the script solved the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57510415/2404470)

2. Added some files with `.ts` extension to the project.
3. Now when I run `tsc` to transpile `.ts` files to `.js` files - I get the following error:

> error TS5014: Failed to parse file 'tsconfig.json': Unexpected token / in JSON at position 31.

What I have tried to solve this so far:

- [installing `typescript`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47737001/2404470)
- [`npm install typescript --save-dev`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50848518/2404470)
- [I'm already using `cmd` instead of `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60625306/2404470)
- [`tsc -p tsconfig.json`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47427222/2404470)
- [`"rootDir": "./src"` && `"include": ["src/**/*.ts"]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51067118/2404470)
- [There is no erroneous comma at the end of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51067227/2404470)

When I remove all the comments from the auto-generated config, I get the following [valid JSON](https://jsonlint.com/):

```
{
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",

        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

With this `tsconfig.json` in place - when I run `tsc`, I get the following errors:

```
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'strict'.
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'esModuleInterop'.
```

When I use [the standard config](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-a-node-project-with-typescript) and run `tsc` I get the following errors:

```
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'esModuleInterop'.
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'moduleResolution'.
```

Dependencies in the `package.json` are:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
  "tslint": "^6.1.2",
  "typescript": "^3.9.5"
},
"dependencies": {
  "express": "^4.17.1"
}
```

**Environment**

```
npm -v : 6.13.4
node -v : v12.16.1
tsc -v : Version 1.5.3
Windows 10
```

This is a very first step towards making a typescript project and if there are so many problems - how can one make a project?

## Is there a simple straight forward "working" way to set up a node.js typescript project?

Comment: Can you share your dependencies?

Comment: @Baboo_ shared the dependencies in the question

Comment: I suggest trying deno instead of node. https://deno.land/ no need for literally any dependencies at all, it supports typescript natively.

Comment: @ChrisRollins node is battle-tested and very mature! I would not suggest switching to new technology just because of a problem while the problem is the most basic problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To transpile from `.ts` to `.js`

1. Add `tsc:tsc` script to `package.json`
2. Run `npm run tsc` instead of `tsc`